# mysql and databases with wsl and visual studio

Tags: python, mysql, linux, database, wsl-2

I downloaded mysql in my windows system
and I download it too to my visual studio
I connect my visual studio with wsl with my ubunto 20.4
when I try to run mysql with sudo mysql

I got this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

and when I run with `mysql -u root -p`
I got this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

when I stop mysql and start it again
I got this:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

and I am sure the password is correct
what's the problem?

I connect my visual studio with wsl with my ubuntu 20.4
when I try to run mysql with sudo mysql
I got this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

and when I run with `mysql -u root -p`
I got this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

when I stop mysql and start it again
I got this:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

and I am sure the password is correct.

Comment: Even after my edit it's still pretty spaghetti ... you may have to also elaborate on what you mean by which things. `I download it too to my visual studio` means nothing to me.

Comment: use host 127.0.0.1 that forces mysql to try tcpip

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.